# Use Javascript to edit Dynamic binding gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have an dynamic asp.net gridview and there are no boundfields available.

I have "Edit" and "Update/Cancel" button. On click of Edit button, I want javascript to fetch 4th cell and convert it to textbox.

Once they click Update button, I want the selected value to go to get saved in DB.

Can anyone provide me pointers for this functionality?

I dont want all cells of row to be edited but since I dont have boundfield, I am not able to make anything specific readonly. Hence I want to use javascript approach.

Comment: You can use `EditTemplate` if you want to edit it inside `gridview`

Comment: The fields are getting generated dynamically and columns vary as per selected option. So we don't have EditTemplate.

Comment: (if you are using `jquery`) entire `gridview` will be rendered as a `table` on client side, so on click of any button in a cell, you can get `tr` as `var row = $('btn').closest('tr')`, then use `row.find('id')` to get any element in that row.

Comment: Ok, Will try to use this.

Comment: If you already have an `Edit` button that I suppose it works OK, why don't you put you grid inside an `asp:UpdatePanel` control?

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net grid view you have select button !!!
you can write a function for this button for save your Row ID in static int variable !!!
And then you can write java script method for show edit panel with button for save changes and when click on this button you can update your row with ID in static variable Have previously defined :)